# EJS not working with Nodejs - Information is not showing in EJS correctly

Tags: node.js, ejs

I'm tring to apply a loop in my file 'index.ejs' but that is not showing the information.
Doing some tests I see that the file server.js is extracting the data correctly and the page is listing the `<li>` correctly (there are 4 lines in db and there are 4 `<li>` on HTML structure.

[See my HTML code here:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7wZo.png)

[See my server.js here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Rok.png)

[See the HTML result that I mentioned here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpIVQ.png)

Comment: Please don't post your code as Image !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ejs you're doing `for(var filmes of filmes)` which is reassigning the value of `filmes`, maybe try `for(var film of filmes)`

EDIT: also in li use `<%= film.nomeFilme %>`

Comment: I tried that as well, it shows the samething

Comment: try this for the li `<li><%= film.nomeFilme %></li>`

Comment: I tried, still showing '::marker' on HTML structure instead of the value

Comment: can you provide the current ejs code after these 2 updates?

Comment: I also did a simple test by creating an array and sending this info to the page, and the same thing happens

Comment: @GabrielDonada You're still using <% not <%= in the li